# ¿Como deshabilitar minutos y hacer que los botones de arrow up/down hagan saltos de 15 mins? bootstrap datetimepicker de eonasdan

Tags: javascript, datetime

El plugin que utilizo esta [aquí](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

Lo quiero hacer es deshabilitar los minutos que no voy a utilizar.

Lo que yo utilizare son: `00, 15, 30 y 45`.

O al menos que los botones arrow up/down realicen saltos de 15mins.

```js
     $('#crear_fecha').datetimepicker({
         icons: {
             up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
             down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
         },
            format: 'LT',
          defaultDate: moment().set({minute:0,second:0,millisecond:0}),
         collapse:false,
         sideBySide:true,
         useCurrent:false,
         showClose:true
     })
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/es-do.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
          <input type='text' class="datetimepicker col-sm-4" name='crear_fecha' id='crear_fecha' />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente necesitas establecer la opción [`stepping`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#stepping) igual a `15`.

Ejemplo:

```js
$('#crear_fecha').datetimepicker({
  icons: {
    up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
    down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
  },
  format: 'LT',
  defaultDate: moment().set({minute:0,second:0,millisecond:0}),
  collapse:false,
  sideBySide:true,
  useCurrent:false,
  showClose:true,
  stepping: 15
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/es-do.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <input type='text' class="datetimepicker col-sm-4" name='crear_fecha' id='crear_fecha' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: gracias hermano, no habia visto el stepping.

Comment: disculpa creí que le había dado como respuesta.